# Make flexbox text level to other containers?

Tags: html, css

I have three flexbox containers with varying amount of text and a background image positioned at the top. I am trying to make the top of text and image level but it keeps pushing upwards. How can I make the text flow downwards and be level?
I don't want to set a max height as I'll have a different amount of text on each webpage and there will be too much whitespace.
Thanks.

```css
body {
  width: 1200px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column row;
  padding: 0px;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  color: black;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box1 {
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  color: black;
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
  background-size: 70px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 97% 0%;
  order: 1;
}

.box2 {
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
  background-size: 70px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 97% 0%;
  order: 2;
}

.box3 {
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
  background-size: 70px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 97% 0%;
  order: 3;
}

.box ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
}

.box li {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  right: 30px;
  top: 2px
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box1">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="box3">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For one thing there is no such thing as `flex-flow: column row;`. Do you have an image of what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Remove the `margin-auto` too - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/MGmZXR

Comment: Thank you. Removing margin-auto fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your divs do not align is `margin: auto` on the boxes.

Set the margin to 0, or remove the `margin: auto` if it is not needed.

```
.box > div {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

See this for reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/d2LgLvx2/

Comment: Thank you so much! It was something so simple.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped you! Please click the green checkmark next to the answer that helped you, so the question gets marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use `display:table` for container and `display:table-cell` for children.

```css
*body {
  width: 1200px;
}

.box {
  display: table;
  /*   flex-flow: column row; */
  padding: 0px;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  color: black;
  margin: auto;
}

.box1 {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  color: black;
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
  background-size: 70px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 97% 0%;
  order: 1;
}

.box2 {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
  background-size: 70px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 97% 0%;
  order: 2;
}

.box3 {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
  background-size: 70px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 97% 0%;
  order: 3;
}

.box ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
}

.box li {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  right: 30px;
  top: 2px
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box1">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="box3">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margin from `.box ul` to have the text moved to top of the box divs.

Also, set the flex-flow of `.box` to `flex-flow: row nowrap`. Then add a new property of `align-items: flex-start`

Edit:

```
.box ul{
  margin: 0;
}

.box{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  padding: 0px;
  color: black;
  justify-content: space-between; 
  align-items: flex-start;
```